# how does irqfd trigger interrupt in the guest

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, virtualization, kvm

I'm trying to understand `irqfd's` and how KVM can interrupt the guest and have it execute its interrupt handler. This [document](https://xzpeter.org/htmls/2017_12_07_kvm_irqfd/kvm_irqfd_implementation.html) mentions binding a file descriptor to an interrupt but the entire flow of interrupt propagation from KVM to guest kernel isn't fully clear. The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68456407/how-does-generating-an-interrupt-calling-irqfd-calls-an-interrupt-on-the-kvm-v) mentions emulating a HW pin, how does that work? What triggers the guest to schedule its ISR?